# SugarCRM CE: upgrade from 6.5.9 to 6.5.11 Fails with "ZIP Error(0): Status(0): Arhive(upload://SugarCE-6.5.11.zip)"

Tags: upload, compression, upgrade, sugarcrm

I have a fresh running installation of SugarCRM Version 6.5.9 (Build 8653) hosted at Bluehost.com (shared hosting)

When I use the upgrade wizard, the system checks are all successful. 
Then I get the dialog where I need to select the package to load, I select "SugarCE-6.5.11.zip" that I hhave just downloaded and click upload.
The upload starts, then fails with the following message:
**ZIP Error(0): Status(0): Arhive(upload://SugarCE-6.5.11.zip): Directory(/home2/jilbeeto/public_html/sugar/cache/upgrades/temp/H6CY1R)**
The parameters of My PHP.ini all exceed the recommendations given in this document:

http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/01_Sugar_Editions/01_Sugar_Ultimate/Sugar_Ultimate_6.5/Sugar_Ultimate_Installation_and_Upgrade_Guide_6.5.0#Upgrade_prerequisites

Any help with this is more than welcome!

Comment: Try downloading it again, it looks like it is corrupted/truncated. Try to unzip locally.

Comment: That 6.5 document link is out of date... try this one: https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/6.5/Ult/Installation_and_Upgrade_Guide/#Prerequisites

Answer (score 1):

You should use an upgrade, not full SugarCRM package. Try [SugarCE-Upgrade-6.5.x-to-6.5.11.zip](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sugarcrm/1%20-%20SugarCRM%206.5.X/SugarCommunityEdition-6.5.X%20Upgrade/SugarCE-Upgrade-6.5.x-to-6.5.11.zip?r=&ts=1375188336&use_mirror=heanet).

Answer (score 0):

Try uncompressing and then compressing the module, before upload.  That works for this headache.

Like comment of vonbrand